# Game collection database software that automatically syncs games from Steam and other online shops?

Tags: windows, collection-manager

My (mostly digital) games collection grew so large and the places I shop are so many I fail to keep track of what I own and from where.

I am looking for a Windows app where I can keep all my games (digital distributions and retail boxed) in one list so that I can view, sort (and ideally backtrack my purchases) etc.

I found 2 apps for that so far: "Collectorz.com Game Collector" and "Sisimizi".
Neither seem to be able to sync with any online shop (Steam, Origin, Windows Live, GamersGate, GoG, …) and my game library there.

Do you know of an app that can do this for me?

I prefer to have a Win app for this as online services are usually slow and clumsy (plus they can go offline with your whole DB at any time).

Comment: This may not answer your question, but there is a functionality on Steam that allows you to add non-Steam games to your Steam library (http://puu.sh/bGcL2/0bcad69f96.jpg). It is basically a shortcut for your games, so you can keep your entire game collection on Steam.

Comment: @Antithese - Thanks for a tip. I know about that. -- The problems with that though are 1. you would have to add every game, one by one, manually. 2. Steam imho is very bad game collection manager to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [LaunchBox](http://www.launchbox-app.com), it can import games from Steam and gets metadata from [TheGamesDB.net](http://thegamesdb.net/)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We like our answers to be full fledged personal recommendations, rather then a link and "that works". Do you have any experience with the program? If so how is it? What are its ups and downs? How does it fit the needs of the question? Does it have a neat UI? - Add a screenshot? Hope to see you around! (and keep in mind that you can always [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/17203/edit) your questions.)

Comment: Apologies for not accepting the answer for so long. -- At the end I wrote my own windows app to solve the problem (and many other) just the way I wanted it. And I still didn't get to try the LaunchBox. -- Accepting now anyway as it might be very useful to others.